# Python BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer - callback for start and stop event

Tags: python, http, callback, basehttpserver

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html

I have the following code snippet which uses `Python BaseHTTPServer` to run a basic HTTP server.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

# http request handler
class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print "I have just received a HTTP request through POST"

try:
    server = HTTPServer((<ip>, <port>), HttpHandler)

    # wait forever for incoming http requests!
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.socket.close()
```

What I am looking for is a way to get a callback whenever the http server is started/stopped using `server.serve_forever()`/`server.socket.close()` methods.

Say we have the following functions:

```
def http_server_start_callback():
    print "http server has just been started" 

def http_server_stop_callback():
    print "http server has just been stopped"
```

I want `http_server_start_callback` function to be called right after (whenever) I start the server i.e. `server.serve_forever()` and I want `http_server_stop_callback` function to be called right after (whenever) I stop the server i.e. `server.socket.close()`

It would be excellent to configure the http server with the following callbacks:

- before starting the server
- after starting the server
- before stopping the server
- after stopping the server

Is there a way to setup these callbacks in `Python BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer`?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It would be excellent to configure the http server with the following
>   callbacks:
>
> - before starting the server
> - after starting the server
> - before stopping the server
> - after stopping the server

Bear in mind that the OS will start accepting and queuing TCP connections the moment the socket starts listening, which is done in the constructor of `BaseHTTPServer`, so if you want to perform lengthy tasks before starting the server, it's probably better to do them before the OS starts accepting connections.

There's a `server_activate()` method which makes the call to `socket.listen()`, so it's probably best to override that.

Similarly, the OS will continue to accept connections until the call to `socket.close()`, so if you want to be able to define a 'pre-stop' handler which has the capacity to prevent itself from being shutdown, it's probably better to use the `server_close()` method, rather than calling `socket.close()` directly.

I've put together a simple example, using class methods on the request handler to handle the four new events, although you can move them somewhere else...

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

# Subclass HTTPServer with some additional callbacks
class CallbackHTTPServer(HTTPServer):

    def server_activate(self):
        self.RequestHandlerClass.pre_start()
        HTTPServer.server_activate(self)
        self.RequestHandlerClass.post_start()

    def server_close(self):
        self.RequestHandlerClass.pre_stop()
        HTTPServer.server_close(self)
        self.RequestHandlerClass.post_stop()


# HTTP request handler
class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    @classmethod
    def pre_start(cls):
        print 'Before calling socket.listen()'

    @classmethod
    def post_start(cls):
        print 'After calling socket.listen()'

    @classmethod
    def pre_stop(cls):
        print 'Before calling socket.close()'

    @classmethod
    def post_stop(cls):
        print 'After calling socket.close()'

    def do_POST(self):
        print "I have just received an HTTP POST request"


def main():

    # Create server
    try:
        print "Creating server"
        server = CallbackHTTPServer(('', 8000), HttpHandler)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Server creation aborted"
        return

    # Start serving
    try:
        print "Calling serve_forever()"
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Calling server.server_close()"
        server.server_close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that I've also moved the call to the constructor into its own `try...except` block, since the `server` variable won't exist if you hit CTRL-C during its construction.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Suppose I run this script. Then where is the server folder? I mean, I have a file (say "numbers.txt"). I will to add it into the server folder and call it (say by "localhost/numbers.txt").

Answer (score 3):

You have to subclass `HTTPServer` and use your class instead `HTTPServer`

```
from __future__ import print_function
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class MyHTTPServer(HTTPServer):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.on_before_serve = kwargs.pop('on_before_serve', None)
        HTTPServer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):

        if self.on_before_serve:
            self.on_before_serve(self)
        HTTPServer.serve_forever(self, poll_interval)


# http request handler
class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print("I have just received a HTTP request through POST")

try:
    server = MyHTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), HttpHandler,
                          on_before_serve = lambda server: print('Server will start to serve in the moment...'))

    # wait forever for incoming http requests!
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.socket.close()
```

Comment: If the callback facility is not available as a part of `HTTPServer`, then the pre-start and post-stop callbacks can be easily faked by calling the callback function just before starting the server using `serve_forever()` and right after stopping the server using `socket.close()`. But the tricky thing is post-start and pre-stop callbacks. Because `serve_forever()` is a blocking function call and any code after that is not reachable. So is there any way to cover post-start (and pre-stop) callbacks?

Comment: What use case do you have for post-start and pre-stop callbacks?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost In my case I want to write to my logs that the server was started successfully.